# How to validate of dimensions in default ImageField?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Have a following rule in the project: the image field is optional and a default image is an uninformed case for the user. Images are sent by the user in django and must have a dimension (width> = 900, height> = 400).

I am trying to validate the dimensions in admin.py, but it is giving problem when I try to register when it has default argument in imagefield.

[image]

Gives an image error not found even though it is in the directory. Without the validation function in admin.py it works normally.

**models.py**

```
class Event(models.Model):
    banner = models.ImageField('banner', upload_to='events/banners', default='events/banners/banner_padrao_eventos.png', blank=True)
```

**admin.py**

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean_banner(self):
        banner = self.cleaned_data.get('banner')
        if banner:
            img = Image.open(banner)
            width, height = img.size

            max_width = 900
            max_height = 400

            if width < max_width or height < max_height:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    'Image is incorrectly sized:% s x% s pixels. Please insert an image with% s x% s pixels.'
                    % (width, height, max_width, max_height))

            if len(banner) > (3 * 1024 * 1024):
                raise forms.ValidationError('Very large image file (maximum of 3MB).')

            name_img, ext = banner.name.split('.')
            if not (ext.lower() in ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg']):
                raise forms.ValidationError('Please use the image in JPG, JPEG or PNG format.')
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError('The loaded image could not be read.')
        return banner
```

How can I make the default image to be considered in the validation?

Answer (score 0):

The file uploaded is Django `InMemoryUploadedFile` file it's not saved in your server yet, `open()` needs that the file exists physically or as `string bytes`. To do that you need the package `PIL.Image` and `io.BytesIO`

```
from io import BytesIO as StringIO
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open(StringIO(banner.read()))
```

So now, `img.size` is a tuple containing your `width` and `height`

```
width, height = img.size
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation.  but, error appears:

img = Image.open (StringIO (banner.read ()))
AttributeError: object 'str' has no 'read' attribute

Comment: sure that banner that `banner` got a file, try `print(banner,type(banner))` before using it, to see its type

Comment: returns the image path:
events/banners/banner_padrao_eventos.png <class 'str'>

Comment: where your file come from?

Comment: The image is inside the media folder, where is the whole image registered in apps with django-admin

app events:
media/events/banners/banner_padrao_eventos.png

Comment: the way that I show is only for `InMemoryField` I thought the file was supposed to be uploaded by a user when submit a form

Comment: If you want to display a default image in template, better to put the file in your static directory and call it in template with `{% static 'path/to/image' %}`